# how to or when to use GAE @classmethod properly

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I have this google app-engine datastore NDB model:

```py
class pySessions(ndb.Model):
    # sid is the key/id
    data = ndb.Blobproperty(required=True)
    expiry = ndb.DateTimeProperty(required=True) 

    @classmethod                                                                                                                                                              
    def get_sid(cls, sid):                                                                                                                                                    
        sid_key = ndb.Key(cls, sid)                                                                                                                                           
        return cls.query(cls.key == sid_key,                                                                                                                                        
                         cls.expiry >= datetime.utcnow()).get()
```

For getting an specific **sid** I can use something like this:

```py
data = pySessions.get_by_id(sid)
if session and session.expiry >= datetime.utcnow():
    return session.data
return {}
```

Or I could use the `@classmethod get_sid`

```py
data = pySessions.get_sid(sid)
```

Both work but while doing some tests, notice that the `@classmethod` was behaving slower, or not reading the updated session data.

I was testing with a basic counter but after incrementing, I was reloading (header location) the page, is here that I notice that for some unknown reason querying the NBB using the `@classmethod get_sid`was having some issues, the only way I was available to make it work was when using the pdb debugger, since it was making a 'pause' and allowing the code to read the data slowly.

Any idea of what is the difference between using `@classmethod` or a custom query ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you think the speed difference has anything to do with using a classmethod. The two methods are doing completely different things: the classmethod is doing a query (by key and expiry), whereas the other code is doing a straight get, which is *much* quicker, but then only returning if the expiry is less than now.

Queries are always much slower than gets in the datastore, but the second method has the disadvantage of *always* fetching the data - and therefore incurring a cost - even if the expiry date has passed.

The other potential downside of the query is that queries (unlike gets) are subject to eventual consistency, so there is a likelihood of not seeing the most recently updated data.

Comment: The speed difference has to see with the 'eventual consistency' as you properly mention, I notice that when reading fast I wasn't always getting the last stored data but when using 'get_by_id' I always got the stored data

Comment: But both the speed and the consistency are to do with the difference between gets and queries, as I explained.